# Wordpress meta_query not displaying results

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a field with the Adv Custom Fields plugin which allows the user to select which section the page is under (like categories). On each page I'd like to display a sidebar which shows a list of pages with the same section. I attempted to use meta_query and I don't get any results. I would also like to display the parent page first if there's a way to do it. Here's my query:

```
<ul class="test-menu">
<?php 
   $section = get_field('section'); 

   $args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'    => 'section',
            'value'  => $section
         )
      )
   );

   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   ?>

      <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

   <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to specify a post_type in your query and you are missing the compare bit although I'm not sure which one throw you off :

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'    => 'section',
            'value'  => $section,
            'compare' => "="
         )
      )
   );
```

The post type can probably be an array if you have multiple type of custom posts.